# Autocomplete is broken in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, auto-complete, bug

I use Google Chrome as browser. I like the feature that it autocompletes the web-address when I start to type. e.g. when typing "app" it's autocompleted to "apple.stackexchange.com" and I just need to press enter.

But now the autocomplete feature seem to be broken on Mac OS X for me. It works fine on Windows. Now on Mac OS X when I start to type an address it is autocompleted, but just for a small part of a second, then the autocompletion disappear, so I never have the change to press Enter so I can use the autocompletion.

How can I fix this? Is there any settings I can change? or is it a bug?

This didn't work on version 12.0.742.112 and it doesn't work in the current version (13.0.782.107).

Comment: did you clear your cache?

Comment: @bckbck: I tried that now, but it didn't work.

Comment: try going to many many sites and try typing it again. does autocomplete work?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (**[reference](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95656)**):

```
Turning on/off Auto-Suggestions
1. Clear your browsing history
2. Click the Tools menu
3. Select Options
4. Click the Under the Hood tab and find the Privacy section
5. Select/deselect the 'Use a suggestion service to help complete searches and 
   URLs typed in the address bar' checkbox.
6. Click Close.
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this now, but I still have the same problem. The suggestion is shown, but only for a very short period and then disappear.

Comment: Sounds like you may have found a bug (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35309).